# When I click a button, a new form opens. How do I keep this form in the foreground when I click on another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, background-foreground

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mtp1Start = myTrackPanelss1.Start;
            mtp1End = myTrackPanelss1.End;           
            button1.Enabled = false;
            Animation_Radar_Preview ap = new Animation_Radar_Preview();
            ap.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(ap_FormClosing);
            ap.Show();
        }
```

I want that the form `ap` will keep showing display even if i click on other button on the form behind it.
I have one big form and when i click this button a smaller form is open.
I want that the smaller form `ap` will keep showing stay on place when i click on the big form so the smaller form won't move to the back behind the big form.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to show like this,

```
Animation_Radar_Preview ap = new Animation_Radar_Preview();
ap.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(ap_FormClosing);
ap.Show(this);
```

Assign the parameter `this` in `Show()` method. it will set the current form as a owner of child(`ap`).

Answer (score 2):

Set [Form.TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `true`:

```
ap.TopMost = true;
ap.Show();
```